# How do I call a function repeatedly in ARKit from ViewController to recognise objects / images?

Tags: swift, firebase, arkit, google-cloud-vision

I'm designing guided tour app, and I want the app to recognize the landmarks when it's visible to the back camera, and then present info about the landmark using ARkit

In ARKit, I'm trying to recognise landmarks visible to the camera, and  using Google's Firebase / Cloud Vision to identify them.

My problem is I can't get current image from camera in UIimage format to send to Google Cloud API

I've added a button that takes a picture, and written another function that passes the captured image to Firebase and recognises it, but I want the app to recognise the landmark automatically, without having to take a photo.

```swift
@IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let snapShot = self.sceneView.snapshot()

    getLandmarkName(image: snapShot)

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShot, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

}
```

```swift
  func getLandmarkName(image: UIImage) {

    //property for creating instance of Google Cloud Landmark recognition service
    let cloudDetector = vision.cloudLandmarkDetector(options: cloudOptions)

    //property for storing the image from buffer as a vision image
    let cloudImage = VisionImage(image: image)

    if cloudImage != nil {
      print("image object received")
    }

    cloudDetector.detect(in: cloudImage) { landmarks, error in

      guard error == nil, let landmarks = landmarks, !landmarks.isEmpty else {
        // ...
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.landmarkName.text = "No Landmark Detected"
        print("no landmark detected")
        return
      }

      // Recognized landmarks
      for landmark in landmarks {
        let landmarkName = landmark.landmark!
        print("landmark detected: \(landmarkName)")
      }


    }//close landmark detection

  }//close func
```

I've tried calling the fn `swift getLandmarkName` from viewDidUpdate and it only calls it once at the start, which is useless for recognising landmarks as you need it to call repeatedly when holding phone to recognise landmark.

Apparently there's this function as part of ARSessionDelegate

```swift
optional func session(_ session: ARSession, 
            didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session

and it looks exactly like what's required, but I can't figure out how to use or call it. I've tried calling the getLandmarkName from this function but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't take snapshots, use a stream. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/detect-objects for more documentation.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work for Landmark recognition, which is why I've had to use this service instead - https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/recognize-landmarks